# Calculating cutoff frequency for Butterworth filter

Tags: filters, proof, butterworth

I have a problem while calculating cutoff frequency, suppose we have these specs. 
[image]

Firstly, I calculated the order of the filter and got $N=5.8858$ and round it up to get $N=6$.

Now I'm supposed to get $\Omega_c$. Using these equations:

\begin{cases}1+\left(\frac{0.2\pi}{\Omega_c}\right)^{2N} = \left(\frac{1}{0.89125}\right)^2 \quad&\quad (1)\\
1+\left(\frac{0.3\pi}{\Omega_c}\right)^{2N} = \left(\frac{1}{0.17783}\right)^2\quad&\quad (2)
\end{cases}

Now with $N=6$ and $T=1$, substituting in $(1)$

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{0.2\pi}{\Omega_c}\right)^{12} &=\left(\frac{1}{0.89125}\right)^2 - 1 =0.25893\\
\implies (\Omega_c)^{12} &= \frac{{(0.2\pi)}^{12}}{0.25893}\\
 &= 40.29
\end{align}
But in the textbook it says $\Omega_c = 0.7032$, what I did wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the frequency response is for a continuous time filter, whereas the filter specifications are for a discrete-time filter. The piece you are missing is application of the impulse invariance method to go from the continuous time filter to a discrete time filter.

Comment: Yes I know that, those specs are for designing a discrete filter, but it supposes to be mapped into specs for a continuous filter to use one of the "continuous filter designs" like Butterworth in my case. Hence the impulse invariance method job is to do the mapping from a continuous filter into a discrete filter. Correct me if I did a mistake again. Thanks in advance

Comment: you might like the bilinear transform mapping from $s$ to $z$ better than impulse invariant.  but to each his own.

Comment: can you explain how did you calculate order and from where those equations come from to calculate Wc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everythng is alright. You made a mistake in the final calculation.

$$\Omega_c^{12} = \frac{{(0.2\pi)}^{12}}{0.25893} \implies \Omega_c = \sqrt[12]{\frac{{(0.2\pi)}^{12}}{0.25893}} =\frac{0.2\pi}{\sqrt[12]{0.25893}} = 0.7032$$

which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I knew my mistake, I was assuming that $\pi = 180$ but I tried with $\pi=3.1415...$ Can I just ask you why did we use it like that and not $180 degrees$

Comment: Because $\pi$ is $\pi$ and not $180º$. Don't get confused with these two quantities, they are not the same thing, even though sometimes they are "equivalent" in a sense. However, in this case you can see that $\Omega_c$ must be a scalar, and if you don't use $\pi=3.14...$ then you would have units of degrees, which would be nonsense.

Comment: @Tendro  Thanks again, now I got it. Especially for the part "$\Omega_c$ must be a scalar"